# How do I ignore the 1st record in a table when using the get and subscribe using Angular?

Tags: angular

How do I ignore the 1st record in a table when using the get and subscribe using Angular? using the code below:-

```
getAdmins() {

    this.data = [];
    this.api.getAdminList()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = data;

          if (this.isFirstLoad) {
            this.isFirstLoad = false;
            this.dtTrigger.next();
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

My data layout as follow:-

- 1   Administrator Administrator email
- 7   Mr x          Mr x email
- 10  Miss x        Miss x email

I want to ignore the Administrator record but start to display the record from Mr x onward.

Comment: what does the response data look like ?

Comment: Admin Id., Admin Name, Admin Email, User Group and Action. - The 1 record display like this 1. Administrator, Admin Email.

Comment: I mean what is the shape of the response, is it just a normal array ? If so, @dnunez32 answer will work, if it's more intricate, you need to show the reponse type in the question

Comment: The data is from a table of record.  Record 1 to 2 and beyond. I want to display  the 2 record on wards on HTML, but not to display the 1 record.

Comment: then all the answer should be good for you case

Answer (score 1):

```js
getAdmins() {
    this.data = [];
    this.api.getAdminList()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = data.shift(); //The shift() command will remove the first element of the array
        }
      );
}
```

Comment: I am very new in Angular, I getting a error cannot find name datalist.

Comment: sorry it was my typo.. please replace datalist by just data :)

Comment: I have try you method but it does not wok.

Comment: Could you console.log(data) before and after data.shift()?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Array splice

```js
    this.api.getAdminList()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if(data.length > 0) {
            this.data= data.splice(0,1);
          }
        });
```

or try reversing the array and then popping the last item

```js
    this.api.getAdminList()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if(data.length > 0) {
            this.data = data.reverse().pop();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using splice?

```
this.data = [];
this.api.getAdminList()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.data = data.length > 1 ? data.splice(0, 1) : [];
    }
  );
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: I did. It will just show the 1st and ignore the others. What I want is ignore the 1st record and read from the 2nd on wards

Comment: Give this a try: https://jsfiddle.net/pem7w612/ You'll see it removes the first one and shows the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
this.api.getAdminList().pipe()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.data = data.splice(1);
    }
  );
```